# How to access and serve the static files in express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a server.js like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app=express();
app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.send(index.html); //this is stupid

});
app.listen(3000);
```

i have the index file in the same directory as that of server.js

Please guide.

Comment: if the index in the same directory, add this line app.use(express.static(__dirname)); else create another dir name it public then app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at their docs at all?  There's mention of static file serving in the FAQ, for example: http://expressjs.com/faq.html

Answer (score 1):

Write this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Put all public static files in /public folder